# SQLAlchemy Core - Add a Where condition to a preexisting select(...)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I want to create a function that takes in a generic `select`, which assumes a particular column exists in the select, and then add a where condition on this column. Here is the setup:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import select

metadata = MetaData()

Foo = Table(
    'foos', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer),
    Column('foo', String),
    Column('status', String),
)

Bar = Table(
    'bars', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer),
    Column('bar', String),
    Column('status', String),
)
```

The following is along the lines of what I would like, however it results in a natural join:

```
def add_common_where_conditions(sel):
    return sel.where(sel.c.status == 'ACTIVE')

def get_foos():
    sel = select([Foo])
    sel = add_common_where_conditions(sel)
    print(sel)

def get_bars():
    sel = select([Bar])
    sel = add_common_where_conditions(sel)
    print(sel)
```

The output of `get_foos()` is:

```
SELECT foos.id, foos.foo, foos.status 
FROM foos, (SELECT foos.id AS id, foos.foo AS foo, foos.status AS status 
FROM foos) AS anon_1 
WHERE anon_1.status = :status_1
```

I'm not sure how I can get a reference to the original table. For example I tried this, but it only gets a reference to the subquery:

```
>>> sel = select([Foo])
>>> sel.c[0].table
<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Subquery at 0x1d360b7dba8; anon_1>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use the `select`'s [froms](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.froms) attribute:

```py
sel = select([Foo])
sel = sel.where(sel.froms[0].c.status == 'Active')
print(sel)
```

Produces

```
SELECT foos.id, foos.foo, foos.status 
FROM foos 
WHERE foos.status = :status_1
```

Comment: It works but it assumes the first column of the select is from the table that contains the column to which you want to apply the where clause. That would always work if the select was querying a single table, but it may fail for joins. Of course you can loop the `froms` yourself and figure it out. I just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67255904/1391717) using the new `selected_columns` which is available in 1.4 which seems to work great. The only problem is that most people are on 1.3 or lower. It would be nice if there was a native way to do this in 1.3...

Comment: Yes, for multiple tables you'd have to do the work to find the right one(s).

Comment: One problem with this `selected_columns` is that (as you might infer from the name) you can only apply the where condition to a column that was selected. So for example if you wanted to select A and B but filter on C, `selected_columns` would not work. In this case `froms` would be better since you have access to all columns on the underlying table, not just the selected columns.

Answer (score 3):

In SQLAlchemy 1.4 you can use the new [selected_columns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_14.html#a-select-statement-is-no-longer-implicitly-considered-to-be-a-from-clause) attribute, which the documentation says can be used for this very thing:

```
def add_common_where_conditions(sel):
    return sel.where(sel.selected_columns.status == 'ACTIVE')

sel = select([Foo])

print(add_common_where_conditions(sel))
```

This outputs the expected:

```
SELECT foos.id, foos.foo, foos.status 
FROM foos 
WHERE foos.status = :status_1
```

However, with this approach you cannot apply the where condition to columns that were not specified in the selected columns. For example, this would fail:

```
sel = select([Foo.c.id])
sel = sel.where(sel.selected_columns.foo = 'hello')
```